# AngularFirebase transaction and batch writes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

```
constructor(
     private afs: AngularFirestore,
    ) {}

dbAdd(){

this.afs.collection()

this.afs.firestore.collection()

}
```

What is the difference between these two (this.afs.collection() & this.afs.firestore.collection()) ? And when to use each of them? Because during transaction and batch we have to use **this.db_cloud.firestore.collection()** and while reading data use **this.db_cloud.collection()**

Answer (score 1):

Basically what happens is that AngularFire2 does not support Transactions natively, so it has to rely on the underlying framework to do it, which is what `this.afs.firestore` does - it calls the Firestore SDK to make the transaction for it.

So when should you use `this.afs.firestore`? Whenever you have to do something that is not natively implemented in AngularFire but that exists in the official SDK. Transactions and Batches are an example of that.

For reference you can check this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/201) where the implementation of that feature for AngularFire is discussed.

Comment: @Shubhendu If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
Following these simple rules you increase your own reputation score and at the same time you keep us motivated to answer your questions.